# More Django projects are overwritting memcached

Tags: django, memcached

on my server I have one project in Django with combination Nginx + Gunicorn. I use memcached in this project and it works fine to me.

Now I would like to add next project. Everything is fine since I add caching to my new project. Then this two projects are overwritting cache of the other one. When I go to page of one project, I see the second.

In my settings.py I have:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    ...
```

and

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backend.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

What have I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the value of `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX` in your settings. It should be unique for each project.